# How to get Resharper to show "private" on members and "internal" on classes as redundancy errors?

Tags: c#, resharper

For class members the `private` modifier is redundant.

For classes the `internal` modifier is redundant.

Is it possible to get Resharper to show these as code errors?

Comment: It can definitely be done in formatting, which you could apply on save most likely.

Comment: Your assumption here is that redundancy is bad. But redundancy aids understanding. Vwls r mstly rdndnt ND unncsry, but it sure is easier to read with them there.

Comment: I would also add that a "redundant" token communicates nothing to the *compiler*, which will ignore it, but certainly does communicate to the *human reader* of the code. When I see `internal class C` this says to me "the developer of `C` *intends* it to be an implementation detail of this assembly. When I see `class C` it could be that the developer intends it to be internal, it could be that the developer intends it to be public and is coming from another language where classes are public by default, it could be that they intend to make it public later, it's very hard to say.

Comment: For a similar reason, I object to removing the redundancy of field initializers, like `private int whatever = 0;`. The memory allocator will take care of initializing int fields to zero for you, but I would want this to be kept in the source code. It tells me that the initialization to zero was *by design* and not an *accident*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: no.

We have only 'code cleanup' functionality able to remove redundant `private`/`internal` modifiers, but no code inspection like this. This easily can be done via plugin or issue request :)

Comment: thought so. i will raise a feature request. in the short term can u point me to a plugin that does something similar?

Answer (score 0):

There is no default out-of-the-box rule that enforces this. And I must say that I haven't seen a coding guideline in the last years that ever suggested *not* specifying the access level on anything. Usually specifying the access level is seen as a good thing, since it shows that there has been at least some thought into the desired level.

Of course some people set everything to public, but then again, that's something your rule won't see anyway.

You'll need to create a [custom StyleCop rule](http://stylecopplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20Create%20StyleCop%20Custom%20Rule) (with the StyleCop plugin for Resharper) or a [Resharper plugin](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/2.04+Daemons+and+Daemon+Stages+%28R8%29) to detect and flag these issues. It shouldn't be too hard, since the "error" is not too complex and the list acceptance criteria would be short and simple.